Active Admin interface is broken with error `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` in browser console
I run a Ruby on Rails application with Active Admin as an admin backend.
My setup is:
Ruby 2.5.9
Rails 5.2.8.1
ActiveAdmin 2.9.0
Webpacker 4.3.0
I migrated the application from an older VM and updated some underlying technologies resulting in a somewhat broken interface.
Now in most views of the admin backend i get the following error in my browser console:
base.js:18 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at base.js:18:3
    at Object.<anonymous> (base.js:14:66)
    at i (bootstrap:19:22)
    at Module.<anonymous> (active_admin.js:1:1)
    at i (bootstrap:19:22)
    at bootstrap:83:10
    at active_admin-d8e2e3d…0e9be08c9d.js:2:921
(anonym)    @   base.js:18
(anonym)    @   base.js:14
i   @   bootstrap:19
(anonym)    @   active_admin.js:1
i   @   bootstrap:19
(anonym)    @   bootstrap:83
(anonym)    @   active_admin-d8e2e3d….js:2

i tried following steps to solve the issue:

i ran bundle exec rails generate active_admin:assets --use_webpacker
i added this line to my config/initializers/active_admin.rb

config.use_webpacker = true


i ran rails g active_admin:webpacker

i got these steps from an issue within the activeadmin github repository:
https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/309
Also i already checked similar Questions and nothing seems to help here.
can anyone help me with this issue? I Assume, that other issues in my Rails application have theire cause in this problem.
Thanks in advance and best regards
EDIT:
Since i can not format code in the comment i add the Answer to @engineersmnky comment here:
In app/assets/javascripts/active_adminjs i've added the first line:
//= require jquery
//= require active_admin/base

Additionally in my application.js there are these lines:
//= require jquery
//= require rails-ujs
//= require activestorage
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .

Also i think, that this should make jquery globally available is this in my config/webpack/plugins/jquery.js
const webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  "$":"jquery",
  "jQuery":"jquery",
  "window.jQuery":"jquery"
});


$ is usually jQuery. Have you confirmed that jQuery is loaded before base.js?

In app/assets/javascripts/active_adminjs i've added the first line:
//= require jquery //= require active_admin/base
Additionally in my application.js there are these lines:
//= require jquery //= require rails-ujs //= require activestorage //= require turbolinks //= require_tree .
Also i think, that this should make jquery globally available is this in my config/webpack/plugins/jquery.js
`
const webpack = require('webpack')
module.exports = new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
"$":"jquery",
"jQuery":"jquery",
"window.jQuery":"jquery"
});
`

The simplest option here is probally to just link to jQuery as an external instead of bundling it. https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/

That sounds promising. I'll try that as soon, as i fixed another problem i have with my Rails Application. Cant build the assets at the moment. Thanks so far! Didn't want you to think, that i just left this question without any reaction.

The solution was simpler than i thought...
The problem was that the way my other Rails Gem was handling webpacker interfered with ActiveAdmin in webpacker mode. So i had to run ActiveAdmin with Sprockets, which is the default, and the error was gone.
See this issue from the applications GitHub:
https://github.com/codevise/pageflow/issues/2098#issuecomment-2069653752
Thanks to everyone that helped.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
